# MySQL and PHP looping function inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a MySQL query to return products based on id using the following code:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['psearch-name'] ) ) {
    // Get products matching the id
        $sql        = mysql_query(' select * from products where id = "' . $_POST['psearch-name'] . '" ');  
        $products   = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $purchases  = mysql_query(' SELECT * FROM `products_purchases` WHERE product_id = ' . $products['id'] . ' ');   

        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($purchases);
        echo $num_rows;

        while($product = mysql_fetch_assoc($purchases)) {

            ile_product($product['product_id'], $product['user_id'], $product['date']);

        }

}
```

The `$num_rows` returns `29` which is the correct value, but inside the `while` loop the function `ile_product()` only runs once. Any ideas why isn't it running this function for every row?

Comment: Lovel [sql injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your server pwn3d. and check what `$product` is after that one call to ile_product (`var_dump($product)`). if it's boolean false, then the fetch failed. either that's because there's no more data, or something blew up and it can't fetch the other 28 rows. either way, look at mysql_error() for clues as to what might have gone wrong.

Comment: @MarcB +1 for that, is using PDO too much to ask. these guys like using deprecated functions without even sanitizing them.

Comment: Apart from using the ancient `mysql_query` function, you're not checking for errors here. Anything could be going wrong and you'd have no idea. PDO, by way of examples, can be configured to throw exceptions so errors are impossible to miss.

Comment: @PlatinumIndustries: given how many bad/wrong/hideously outdated "tutorials" for php are floating around, it's no surprise people start banging out crap code and pat themselves on the back for doing so.

Comment: @MarcB - yea, sadly, most tuts are outdated and most don't cover new methods thoroughly.